# looking for a robot to buy

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My laboratory is going to buy a robot for research within the prize range of 7200 us dollars. Would you please suggest one with following features as much as possible?

1. Ros supported
2. Simulation feature
3. Kinect sensor
4. Having an arm
5. Good mobility

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202211/looking-for-a-robot-to-buy/) by [Ahyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19943/ahyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ahyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19943/ahyan/) on 2015-02-03**:
Any suggestion pls?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-02-03**:
I'm not aware of any robots with those features in that price range; sorry.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2015-02-11**:
Especially the arm requirement will be tricky. Decent robot arms start around 25.000 €, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In that price range getting a powerful robot is difficult, but you can have a look at the [Corobot](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/Corobot). Also check [here](http://www.robotshop.com/en/coroware-corobot-cb-l.html). It comes in a price range of around 4500 USD. You will still have to get an arm for your robot or build one from scratch like the [turtlebot_arm](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_arm).

---

Originally posted by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) with karma: 654 on 2015-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ahyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19943/ahyan/) on 2015-02-06**:
Thank you for your suggestion